# How to scroll in mobile testing (appium and webdriverio) in android within coordinates

Tags: javascript, android, automated-tests, appium

I have to handle with coordinates, because I'm going to run the test in different devices.
The thing is that in some test, I have to scroll to an element, I know that in ios I can click even if the element is not showed, but in android I need to scroll up or down, and after do the action with it.
I'm using webdriverIo, appium and javascript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two options

1-

```
await $('andorid=new UiScrollable(new
    UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollTextView("**[your element
    here]**")').click();
```

2-

```
await $('andorid=new UiScrollable(new
        UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollToEnd(1,5)')
```